# Visit a URL with a variable altering the url, windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have a URL that is shown below:
URL is taken out due to contract reasons

```
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.URLhere.aspx?stopid=4556");
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler
            (webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
            webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);
```

I need to find a way to alter the end part, so change 4556 from a text block, into another text so that when the application send the request it finds the whole lot.

I thought you could do this:

```
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.URLhere.aspx?stopid=" + stopId);
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler
            (webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
            webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);
```

How does one do this?

Edit:
When i do the code above it returns as a null reference, so i am asuming it's not getting the text in the textbox.

Comment: I really can't understand what's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing the encoding of your variable.

```
var myvar = "the simpsons";
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.URLhere.aspx?stopid=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myvar));
```

See [HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)

Comment: Thanks i slightly improved it to change the value to what the user inputs. But thanks for helping me to get there.

Comment: How would one do this? service.aspx?routes=true&timetables=true&maps=true&serviceid=1149&xsl=json 

I would nee to change the serviceid would it be the same solution above but adding this on the end?

Comment: Sorry, what? Just create your string, which is the URL. anything that isn't hardcoded (i.e. variables), use HttpUtility.UrlEncode on before you concatenate the string.

Answer (score 0):

there is no difference between

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.URLhere.aspx?stopid=4556");
```

and

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.URLhere.aspx?stopid=" + stopId);
```

so i really don't know whats your problem

Answer (score 0):

Henry, 
If I understand you question correctly, I think you want to append the value in a TextBox (not a TextBlock) to the URI. If that is correct and you're employing MVVM, you could bind your TextBox to a public property on the ViewModel (lets call it TextBoxProp)

```
private string _textBoxProp;
public string TextBoxProp
{
   get{return _textBoxProp;}
set
{
   _textBoxProp = value;
   RaisePropertyChanged("TextBoxProp");
}
}
```

and then create your URI as follows:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format("http://www.URLhere.aspx?stopid={0}", TextBoxProp));
```

Be sure when you bind to the property in XAML that you set the mode to TwoWay.
I hope that helps